# SAP UI5 DropDown Control is not getting refreshed

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a dropdown control in view and button which should all the values in page. Basically which acts like refresh button

Now when I select on value from the drop down and when I clicked the Clear button.
I am using the below code for refresh the view

View name is Metrics.

I am deleting the content and adding the same

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId("idContainer").removeAllContent();

var view = sap.ui.getCore().byId("idMetrics");
sap.ui.getCore().byId("idContainer").addContent(view);
```

The value in the button is not getting cleared. I have used several methods provided in the UI5 API reference library to clear the content
But the value not getting clear

Can you please let me know how to clear the value from the Drop down
I am using the list Item to add the contents to the DropDown

Thanks
Pawan Akella

Comment: Pawan, Clearing the dropdown values on click of the button.Is this is your requirement?If not please mention the exact requirement.

Comment: Hi Rob, yes this is my requirement and i am using inplaceedit control to attached drp down values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values you write into the Controls will be saved in the Core, so you should give each Control a DataBinding and use `setData` to set them empty

**Option one**:

Completely empty Data Object

```
var aData = {};
sap.ui.getCore().getModel("YourModel").setData(aData);
```

Option two:

You define all the control-contents that should be default and put them into an object and then set these Data

```
var defaultPartnerDaten = {
    archived: "", 
    nummer: "", 
    anrede: "",
    vorname: "DefaultData", 
    nachname: "",
    date: "", 
    strasse: "DefaultData",
    hausnummer: "",
    plz: "", 
    ort: "",
    land: "",
    teles: [],
    faxs: [],
    mobils: [],
    emails: [],
    bankverbindungen: [],
    kfz: "",
    schein: "",
    schaden: "",
    typ: "",
    ortsteil: "",
    nation: ""
};
```

The controls which are DataBinded to `vorname` and `strasse` will have the value `DefaultData`